# If $2^{x + 1} < y$, then what is the largest polynomial in $x$ that cannot be an upper bound for $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

**Update**: *I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632967)*.

The title says it all.

> If $2^{x + 1} < y$, then what is the largest polynomial in $x$ (of maximum possible degree) that cannot be an upper bound for $y$?

So for example, I know that $y \leq x^2$ cannot happen because $2^{x + 1} < x^2$ does not hold for all *integer* values of $x$.

I was wondering if there was some sort of systematic procedure for finding the largest polynomial $P(x)$ (of maximum possible degree) satisfying the given conditions.

Comment: Isn't the same true for _any_ polynomial? You don't have $2^{x+1} < x^{1\,000\,000}$ either.

Comment: Hold on @Arthur, that inequality is true for $$x \in \left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\right\}$$ and so forth.

Comment: Over what values of x in the Q ?

Comment: @user254665, $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No polynomial  is an upper bound for $2^{x+1}$.

Comment: @user254665 That's what I was trying to say as well. However, as I understand it from the comments, the OP might be trying to find the highest degree polynomial that is bounded by $2^{x+1}$ for all $x\in \Bbb N$? In that case, $x^{1\,000\,000} - C$ for some constant $C$ works, and so does any other degree.

Comment: Okay, I am in the process of asking a follow-up question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ can be greater than 1 then no polynomial is an upper bound for $2^{x+1}$.

Consider the polynomial $x^n$

We can see if $x^n > 2^{x+1}$ for very large values of $x$

$\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} \frac{2^{x+1}}{x^n}$

Using the ratio test the ratio is $\frac{\frac{2^{x+2}}{(x+1)^n}}{\frac{2^{x+1}}{x^n}}= \frac{2^{x+2}}{2^{x+1}}\cdot \frac{x^n}{(x+1)^n} = 2$ Therefore the limit does not converge. If $x^n$ was an upper bound we would expect the limit to converge to a value between $0$ and $1$.