# If $2^{x + 1} < y$, then what is the "smallest" function of $x$ that cannot be an upper bound for $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

(This is a follow-up question to this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632890).)

The title says it all.

Let $x$ be a positive integer.

> If $2^{x + 1} < y$, then does there exist a *minimum* function $f(x)$ that cannot be an upper bound of $y$?

So for example, I know that $f(x) = x^2$ cannot be an upper bound because $2^{x + 1} < x^2$ does not hold for all *integer* values of $x$.

I was wondering if there was some sort of systematic procedure for finding the *minimum* (or *maximum*, for that matter) function $F(x)$ satisfying the given conditions.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the best function of $x$ to use as **NOT** an upper bound for $y$, is $2^{x+1}$ itself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *minimum*? Because $f(x) = 2^{x+1}+\varepsilon$ is an upper bound for every $\varepsilon >0$ alternatively $f(x) = 2^{x+1} + \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x)$ is such that at some $x = x_0$, we have $f(x_0)<2^{x_0+1}$.

Consider $\frac{f(x)}{2}$...